# Does facebook and google share data?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

I did some google search on cars and the next day i started getting advertisement on cars on Facebook. Do Google and Facebook share browsing data, if so how.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: I agree with you@WizKid. so dev, I found an article that may help you: https://www.quora.com/Does-Google-share-data-with-Facebook-I-searched-for-a-north-face-sleeping-bag-on-Chrome-then-saw-an-ad-for-one-on-Facebook-a-few-hours-later-Why

Comment: @SamuelDiogo that post is really outdated. I decided to ask this question in this community because, i could a good answer with a relevant source on any search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are concurrents, this would seem unlikely. You might however have left some clue that you were searching about cars on Facebook. The algorithm bases itself on pages you've visited. Also, many webpages contain a tracker from Facebook, generally bundled in the "Login with Facebook" button or "Like this page" button. It lets Facebook know you were there. That's probably what happened.